# PHP export to excel on server side

Tags: php, excel

on localhost i can export an excel document that has the right encoding and looks fine. Now when i push it to my server it looses the format and gets wired signs i also get the following error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  realpath() [<a href='http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath'>function.realpath</a>]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect.  The script whose uid is 1348 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in <b>/var/www/zaop.dk/public_html/site/resources/external/PHPExcel/Shared/File.php</b> on line <b>175</b><br />
```

Has anyone tried anything like this and know what to do about it?

also if you need more of my code please comment and il add my export function

Here is my export function:

```
    public function downloadList($excelData) {
    set_time_limit(0);

    require_once './site/resources/external/PHPExcel.php';
    $document = new PHPExcel();
    $activeSheet = $document->getActiveSheet();

    $currColumn = $this->columnStart;
    $currRow = $this->rowStart;

    // Sets the workbook default styles.
    $document->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);

    // Saves the report in the workbook.
    for ($i = 0; $currRow <= count($excelData)+1; $i++) {
        while ($currColumn <= $this->columnEnd) {
            $currCell = $currColumn.$currRow;
            $dataKey = $this->columnKeys[$currColumn];
            $activeSheet->getCell($currCell)->setValue($excelData[$i][$dataKey]);
            $currColumn++;
        }
        $currColumn = $this->columnStart;
        $currRow++;
    }

    // Sets the width of all columns.
    for ($i = $this->columnStart; $i < $this->columnEnd; $i++) {
        $activeSheet->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(true);
    }

    $fileName = 'export.xls';

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    ob_clean();
    flush();

    $excelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($document, 'Excel5');
    $excelWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The folder you are trying to write to must have the same user/group as your script.

Comment: I have the highest possible acess to the server so how can this be?

Comment: It could be a misconfigured server or different fileowners. Did you checked if it is the same for script and directory? Do you have root-access?

Comment: Its not you that is accessing the server its Apache. See if this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966333/include-warning-safe-mode-restriction-in-effect

Comment: @RiggsFolly ive added my export function can you guide me in the right direction?

Comment: It is all about the ownership of the files. Please show them to us. Like Folly said: If you upload it as the user with full permission you have the fileownership. If you are not member of the www-data group apache won't be able to write to the directories you've created!